# Windows Remote Connection Apps Freezing on remote machine

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-11, windows-11-v22h2

Recently (last couple months) I started experiencing an issue with RDP. On my remote machine (desktop), when I remote into it any web browser that was open on the remote machine is frozen and unresponsive. Sometimes after waiting a few minutes it unfreezes but most the time not.

I haven't noticed it happening with any other programs. I believe it may have happened to Steam once.

Desktop (remote machine) - Windows 11 pro

Answer (score 0):

There have been some windows updates that caused issues for Remote Desktop (RDP) use:

- [Windows 11 2022 Update causes issues to Remote Desktop users](https://mspoweruser.com/windows-11-2022-update-causes-issues-to-remote-desktop-users/)
- [Microsoft investigates Windows 11 22H2 Remote Desktop issues](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/microsoft/microsoft-investigates-windows-11-22h2-remote-desktop-issues/)
- [Recent Windows Server updates break VPN, RDP, RRAS connections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/896919/recent-windows-server-updates-break-vpn-rdp-rras-c)

However, [there **is a purported fix** in January, 2023 update **KB5022360** .](https://techdigipro.com/how-to/microsoft-fixes-windows-11-issue-behind-remote-desktop-freezes/)

Therefore,

- First, try applying **KB5022360**.
- If that fails to remedy the RDP issue, try some of the fixes suggested below.

  - [RDP broken due to Windows Update - and how to fix it](https://blog.coeo.com/rdp-broken-due-to-windows-update-and-how-to-fix-it-authentication-error)
  - [Microsoft RDP problems Windows 11 22H2](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-11/microsoft-rdp-problems-windows-11-22h2/m-p/3653483)
  - [KB5021653: Out-of-band update for Windows Server 2012 R2: November 17, 2022](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb5021653-out-of-band-update-for-windows-server-2012-r2-november-17-2022-8e6ec2e9-6373-46d7-95bc-852f992fd1ff)